# In Gaussian Processes, how to understand the hyper-parameters optimization?

Tags: machine-learning

I know that in a GP, hyper-parameters are optimized by maximizing the marginal likelihood. Could anyone explain this method to me please?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Are you after a reference to some texbooks on GP?  Or is there a specific textbook you are reading, that you don't understand?  Are you familar with maximum likelihood in general (eg GLMs)?

Comment: @probabilityislogic  Thanks for your reply~ I am reading the GPML written by Carl Rasmussen. I am reading Chapter 2, I'm not sure how to derive the algorithm shown on page 19, since it does not look the procedure shown before.    In addition, I'm not familiar with ML method... sorry to put you out

Comment: Its ok, you haven't "put me out" - my questions are aimed at better understanding where you are struggling.

Answer (score 2):

In short we want a GP that fits our data well, but not too well that it is overfit and incapable of predicting future data. Balancing these two concerns can be performed maximising the log of the marginal likelihood. Don't be scared by this log because it is a monotonic function and maximising it is the same as maximising marginal likelihood itself.The marginal likelihood is simply 'how probable is the observed data given our GP'. Obviously 2 things can make it more probably, the same as minimising the z-score of an observation with respect to a regular normal distribution.

$$Z = \frac{x - \mu}{\sigma}$$

We can bring the mean function closer to the observations (data fit) and we can increase our uncertainty (complexity).

By varying the hyperparameters we can balance these two components.

Hope this gives you a better intuition!